# How to open a serial terminal in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse-juno

In previous versions of Eclipse I have been able to open a view that presented a serial terminal/console.

How do I do this in Eclipse Juno?

I have a "Terminals" view open and it has text that says:

`To open a terminal, right-click the Terminal subsystem under the target. Then select 'Launch Terminal' from the context menu.`

I really have no idea what this is talking about and I've been using Eclipse for several years now!

Can someone shed some light on this?

**EDIT:**
I've discovered that the "Terminal Subsystem under the target", refers to the "Remote Systems" view. I can't find any options for a serial terminal though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a serial terminal in Eclipse Juno.

**1: Install the software for serial terminals:**

Navigate to: *Help* -> *Install New Software...*

Dropdown list for *Work with:* to say `Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno`

Select: *Mobile and Device Development*, especially *Target Management Terminal* which is "An ANSI (vt102) compatible Terminal including plug-ins for Serial, SSH and Telnet connections."

Click *Next* and anything else to finish the install ...

**2: Open the view**

Navigate to: *Window* -> *Show View* -> *Other ...* -> *Terminal* -> *Terminal*  (NOTE: singular *Terminal*, not plural *Terminals*)

**3: Open a terminal**

The rest should be fairly obvious as the view contains icons to Connect, Disconnect, Settings, etc which are related to Serial, SSH and Telnet connections.

Comment: If you want serial, you also need. The RXTX library 
Help > Software Updates, Add Site and install from:
   http://rxtx.qbang.org/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Under remote systems, there is "Local" and the remote connection, in my case 192.168.1.12. Click on the "+" to open subfolders. You should see the project you are working on. Right click on it. Select "Launch Terminal", the third one from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Load up the Remote Systems perspective to connect to the server. There you will be able to open an SSH terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Incubator project called Local Terminal. You can install it from the Eclipse update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ under *General Purpose Tools->Local Terminal*